# Proper way to check for URL equality

Tags: java, url

I have the following scenario:

```
URL u1 = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
URL u2 = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com");

if (u1.equals(u2)) {
    System.out.println("yes");
}
if (u1.toURI().equals(u2.toURI())) {
    System.out.println("uri equality");
}
if (u1.toExternalForm().equals(u2.toExternalForm())) {
    System.out.println("external form equality");
}
if (u1.toURI().normalize().equals(u2.toURI().normalize())) {
    System.out.println("uri normalized equality");
}
```

None of these checks are succeeding.  Only the path differs: u1 has a path of "/" while u2 has a path of "".  Are these URLs pointing to the same resource and is there a way for me to check such a thing without opening a connection?  Am I misunderstanding something fundamental about URLs?

**EDIT** I should state that a non hacky check is desired.  Is it reasonable to say that empty path == / ?  I was hoping to not have this kind of code

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the 2007 JavaOne :

> The second puzzle, aptly titled "More Joys of Sets" has the user create HashMap keys that consist or several URL objects. Again, most of the audience was unable to guess the correct answer.
>
> The important thing the audience learned here is that **the URL object's equals() method is, in effect, broken**. In this case, two URL objects are equal if they resolve to the same IP address and port, not just if they have equal strings. However, Bloch and Pugh point out an even more severe Achilles' Heel: the equality behavior differs depending on if you're connected to the network, where virtual addresses can resolve to the same host, or if you're not on the net, where the resolve is a blocking operation. So, as far as lessons learned, they recommend:
>
> **Don't use URL; use URI instead**. URI makes no attempt to compare addresses or ports. In addition, don't use URL as a Set element or a Map key.
>   For API designers, the equals() method should not depend on the environment. For example, in this case, equality should not change if a computer is connected to the Internet versus standalone.

---

From the URI equals documentation :

> For two hierarchical URIs to be considered equal, **their paths must be equal** and their queries must either both be undefined or else be equal.

In your case, the two path are different. one is "/" the other is "".

---

According to the URI RFC §6.2.3:

> Implementations **may** use scheme-specific rules, at further processing
>      cost, to reduce the probability of false negatives.  For example,
>      because the "http" scheme makes use of an authority component, has a
>      default port of "80", and defines an empty path to be equivalent to
>      "/", the following four URIs are equivalent:
>
> ```
>  http://example.com
>  http://example.com/
>  http://example.com:/
>  http://example.com:80/
> ```

It seems that this implementation doesn't use scheme-specific rules.

---

**Resources :**

- [sun.com - Java Puzzlers Serves Up Brain Benders Galore](http://java.sun.com/javaone/sf/2007/articles/puzzlers.jsp)
- [javadoc - URI.equals()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#equals(java.lang.Object))
- [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

Comment: ...this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Interesting.. but then the toURI() test would succeed if they were in fact equal.

Comment: @Colin, now *this* answers the question. :)

Comment: Thanks!  Out of curiosity, why did you make it community wiki?

Comment: @SB, I expected that someone could help me to fill the blanks. Well I did it all by myself :) @Zarel, not quite, I'm still looking for a way to do the equality check :)

Comment: @Colin - what do you think of the equality check I propose in my answer?

Comment: @SB, even if it works in your case, it doesn't work with "http://example.com:/" or "http://example.com:80/" I think you could write a URIUtil with a static `equals(URI, URI)` based on the JDK source code but with some additional rules. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/URI.java#URI.equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Ah I see. You are going for the broad case.  In my code, I'm using the same authority as the passed in URL and just fixing the path.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking they are **not** equal. The *optional* trailing slash (/) is only a common usage but not a must. You could display different pages for

```
http://www.yahoo.com/foo/
```

and for

```
http://www.yahoo.com/foo
```

It's even possible for the one you provided I believe the HTTP header could skip that slash.

Comment: Right but can there be logic that changes www.yahoo.com and www.yahoo.com/ ?

Comment: `example.com/foo/` and `example.com/foo` are different, yes, but `example.com` and `example.com/` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can always compare relative URLs with Path.equals-method

ex.

```
Paths.get("/user/login").equals(Paths.get("/user/login/")))
```

produce **true**

You can also use startsWith/endsWith-methods

Comment: there is no class like Paths

Comment: There is `Paths` in `java.nio.file`. For Android requires API 26+.

Comment: Don't use startsWith or endsWith. It's a vulnerability waiting to happen. https://attackerkb.com/topics/AdUh6by52K/cve-2023-46805/rapid7-analysis