# Is there a reliable way to compare two URIs for equality?

Tags: java, url, uri, equality

after some threads I've found out that using the `equals()` method of URL is not as good as the method of URI.

But when I write a JUnit Test and trying to compare

`http://de.wikipedia.com/`

with

`http://de.wikipedia.com`

Or

`http://awebsite.com`

is still not the same like

`www.awebsite.com`

So is there a reliable way (maybe with another library?) for comparing two URL/URI?

Comment: I think that ***equality*** of your second example depends of  DNS settings.

Comment: There's some information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771081/proper-way-to-check-for-url-equality.  There are web sites where the behavior is different   when you use or don't use a trailing `/` in a browser, so I don't think there can be a blanket rule that your first two URI's are equal.

Comment: Well, I've searched a lot - also on stackoverflow.com - but didn't find THIS answer. So this changes everything. Thanks.