# Checking equality of two URLs containing path params

Tags: java

My question is in addition to question asked here : [Proper way to check for URL equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771081/proper-way-to-check-for-url-equality/32257673#32257673)

I am looking for the cleanest way of comparing URLs with path parameters. While comparing, it should ignore the pathParams which is obviously dynamic.

```
e.g. "/myApi/someresource/{resourceId}/employment" 

should match to the string 

"/myApi/someresource/@pathParam/employment"
```

Comment: Well, the cleanest way would be to actually parse the urls into its components and compare those. If you just want to do string comparisons you could replace the parameters with placeholders, e.g. the parameter names.

Comment: I will have 100s of URLs with up to 4 to 5 path parameters, and I am trying to write some generic method which will handle this. If I break down the url in components, I want to ensure "/myApi/someresource/{resourceId}/employment" does not collide with "/myApi/someresource/{resourceId}/employment/" and to treat these 2 as separate URL and then there could be another one like this "/myApi/someresource/{resourceId}/employment/{employmentId}".

Comment: If that is the case, what makes `"{resourceId}"` equal to `"@pathParam"`? They *can* be equal, but don't have to be. If you want to prevent collisions, then all tokens that can potentially be equal need to be specified as potentially equal, or be assumed potentially equal by default. In other words, your use case is well defined, but the task is a bit less trivial than it first seems. A proper utility-method can be written to handle this, but expect to have some work filing out the edges.